# How to reset ng-model value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have write code in ng-change event for input number box in html. and when i change it's value the event is invoked. but i can not change more then 2 value. If i change the model value is rebind from the 1st value. for ex: if i scroll value from 1 to 2 then there is no problem. if i change 2 to 3 then in model it is bind as 1. But i want 3 as model value. I do not know  how to handle this . please help me. thanks in advance.

Here is my html code

```
<input class="numeric" min="1" type="number"
    ng-change="PriceCardItemQtyChanged(this)"
    ng-model="priceCardQtyModel"
    style="width:50px;" />
```

Here the `PriceCardItemQtyChanged()`

```
priceCardModalScope.PriceCardItemQtyChanged = function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < priceCardModalScope.priceCard.length; i++) {
        if (priceCardModalScope.priceCard[i].ConsultationParamId == e.dataItem.ConsultationParamId && priceCardModalScope.priceCard[i].IsSelected == true) {
            priceCardModalScope.priceCard[i].SelectedItemTotalPrice = e.priceCardQtyModel * e.dataItem.ItemPrice;
        }
    }
    calculateTotalAmount();

    return true;
}

function calculateTotalAmount() {
    $scope.selectedItemPriceList = priceCardModalScope.priceCard.filter(getPriceList);

    function getPriceList(e) {
        return (e.IsSelected == true);
    }
    priceCardModalScope.totalPriceAmountModel = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedItemPriceList.length; i++) {
        priceCardModalScope.totalPriceAmountModel = priceCardModalScope.totalPriceAmountModel + $scope.selectedItemPriceList[i].SelectedItemTotalPrice;
    }
}
```

And my error screen is look like this:

[image]

Comment: could you  please give more details?.  priceCardModalScope? e.dataItem?.. your controller details

Comment: ya. pricecardModalScope is an ModelScope which i used as Scope for Popup. and e.dataItem is when i click one row it will fetch the information about that particular row on e.dataitem.

Comment: Is it any kind of grid or uib modal popup>

Comment: this is a kendo grid. and i use template to show the number text box on grid.

Comment: and could youe please share your calculate total function?

Comment: Ya sure. but even if i do not call calculate function too i have same problem.

Comment: i have updated calculate function in question

Comment: if you comment out all the logic inside the ng-change function, are you able see the modal change values?

Comment: could you try with k-ng-model instead of ng-model

Comment: ya i can see the model value. but when i change one value then the function invoked . i have set break point and checked it . when the function execution over then model value again updated then function invoked. it is working like loop. but i do not write code with in loop

Comment: ya i tried with k-ng-model. but i could not get the solution

Comment: hmmm..could you please check whether controller loading twice?..how to you define you controller? Is it like  ng-controller="ctlr" in your html or at youe js file?

Comment: no my controller is loading only once. and i defined controller in js file

Comment: please check by a console.log("check twice") in your controller

Comment: try to use the priceCardQtyModel instead of e.priceCardQtyModel

Comment: if i comment these lines  ' priceCardModalScope.priceCard[i].SelectedItemTotalPrice=priceCardModalScope.priceCardQty * priceCardModalScope.ItemPrice;' these line excuted in PriceCardItemQtyChanged function then i can increment value in text box.

Comment: and i tried both console.log("check twice") and priceCardQtyModel instead of e.priceCardQtyModel. when i use priceCardQtyModel , it shows it is not defined.

Comment: sorry you need to use $scope.priceCardQtyModel

Comment: and please share priceCard array elements too

Comment: ya.. i tried $scope.priceCardQtyModel and priceCardModalScope.priceCardQtyModel too.. but it shows undefined

Comment: ConsultationParamId
:
71
IsSelected
:
true
ItemDescription
:
"Alcane"
ItemPrice
:
90
ItemType
:
"DRUGS"
SelectedItemTotalPrice
:
90 these are all the sample Price Card items

Comment: How it become undeined..it's your model right...assign some default value and try again

Comment: Any luck.. i tried in plunkr [refer](https://plnkr.co/edit/dJi5GbyTleGbeG5XuP6V?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.initial = [{
data1: 10,
data2: 20
}];
$scope.datas = angular.copy($scope.initial);
$scope.reset = function () {
$scope.datas = angular.copy($scope.initial);
// or
// angular.copy($scope.initial, $scope.datas);
   }
  });

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="data in datas">
<input type="text" ng-model="data.data1" />
<input type="text" ng-model="data.data2" />
</div> 
<a ng-click="reset()">Reset to initial value</a>
or
<hr />
<p ng-repeat="data in datas">{{data.data1}}, {{data.data2}}</p>{{initial}}
</div>
```

//Try This Is Example Of Your Requirement .